# Error message 'else' without 'if' when for looping

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Basically, I am trying to nest loop and output something around the lines like this:

```
*  
**  
***  
// (and so on)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting an error message when coding, here is my code (I documented the place where I have an error):

```
for (int i = 0; i< 9; i = i + 2) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");
   for (int j = 1; j<=3; j = j + 1) {
      if (i==8);
        break;
    } else //this else statement is underlined {
       System.out.print("*" + " ");
    }
}
```

---

I am also using java netbeans ide 8.0 if anyone is interested.

Comment: There is no `if` related to the `else` .

Comment: `if (i==8);` should probably be `if (i==8){`. Close for basic syntax error?

Comment: Expanding on Shilly's comment: An `if` is `if (condition) thenStatementList` where `thenStatementList` can be a single statement (followed by a `;`) or a block of statements (`{ ... }`). Your `if` has an empty `thenStatementList` ending with the `;` immediately after `if (i==8)`. You don't want that `;` there.

Comment: The error is itself explaining.

Comment: @ostrichbolol  you dont need to do all that above see my answer below !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in semicolon in the end of if :

```
if (i==8);
//-------^
break;
```

So when you make a semi-colon in the end of if mean that a statement is end start a new statement which is `break;`

to understand more, what did you have do, mean this :

```
if (i==8);//end of statement
break;start a new statement
```

The above is the equivalent of this :

```
if(i==8){
   //do nothing
}
break;
```

To solve your problem you need to use this instead :

```
if(i==8){
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 9; i = i + 2) {
       System.out.print(i + " ");
       for (int j = 1; j<=3; j = j + 1) {
          if (i==8){
            break;
        } else {
           System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i = 1; i<8; i++) {
       System.out.println("");
       for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++) {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

output :

```
*  
* *  
* * *  
* * * *  
* * * * *  
* * * * * *  
* * * * * * *
```

is that what you want??